# Varying the proportional gain of a closed-loop controller but there is no change in the step response

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate the closed loop transfer function of

```
Gcl = (KpGp) / [1 +(KpGp)]
```

I want to see how the step response will change when the proportional gain `Kp` changes from 5 to 15.

I am studying on the effect of `Kp` of the P-controller.

```
A=1.2;
tau=1.4;
td=0.2;
Gp=tf(A,[tau 1],'InputDelay',td);

[y,t]=step(Gp,12);

kp=5;
Gol= series(Kp,Gp);
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y1,t1]=step(Gcl,12);

kp=10;
Gol= series(Kp,Gp);
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y2,t2]=step(Gcl,12);

kp=15;
Gol= series(Kp,Gp);
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y3,t3]=step(Gcl,12);

figure(2);
plot(t1,y1,t2,y2,t3,y3);
grid,title('Step response of plant');
```

However, I keep getting 1 step response. I want to see 3 step responses when k = 5, k = 10 and k = 15.

Here is the step response I am currently getting:
[image: current]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, did I answer your question?

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using the variable `Kp` which is probably a variable set in your MATLAB workspace somewhere before you started running this code, yet you are using `kp` to vary the proportional gain.  Therefore, every time you are trying to change the proportional gain, you aren't because `Kp` is used in every controller you are creating.  Note that this other variable is with a **small case k**.  All you have to do is change  any variables that are `Kp` to `kp` and try again.

```
A=1.2;
tau=1.4;
td=0.2;
Gp=tf(A,[tau 1],'InputDelay',td);

[y,t]=step(Gp,12);

kp=5;
Gol= series(kp,Gp); %// Change
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y1,t1]=step(Gcl,12);

kp=10;
Gol= series(kp,Gp); %// Change
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y2,t2]=step(Gcl,12);

kp=15;
Gol= series(kp,Gp); %// Change
Gcl= feedback(Gol,1);
[y3,t3]=step(Gcl,12);

figure(2);
plot(t1,y1,t2,y2,t3,y3);
grid,title('Step response of plant');
legend('kp = 5', 'kp = 10', 'kp = 15'); %// Change
ylim([0 2]); %// Change
```

Be advised that you chose some proportional gains that are making the control system unstable and so if you tried to plot this without any modifications, the responses that are unstable will overwhelm those that are stable and you won't see them on the plot.  As such, I had to enforce an additional change where the limits of the `y` axis are bounded between 0 and 2.  I also introduced legends into the plot so you can see which plot corresponds to what colour.

This is the plot I get now:

[image]

---

## Minor Note

You can determine what the critical gain is, or the maximum proportional gain you can use before making your system unstable by using the [`margin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/margin.html) command.  This assumes that you are specifying the **open-loop** system (without feedback).  The function thus computes the theoretical maximum proportional gain that you can specify with your system assuming unit-feedback, which is what you're doing.

You can do this by:

```
[Gm,Pm,Wcg,Wcp] = margin(Gp);
```

`Gm` is the gain margin of the system and `Wcg` is the associated frequency of oscillations seen at this critical gain.  The gain margin is also defined as determining what the critical gain would be for our purposes.  `Pm` and `Wcp` are the phase margins and the frequency where the gain is 0 dB, but you can ignore those for the purposes of this question.

`Gm` is the variable you're looking for, and the result we get is:

```
>> Gm

Gm =

    9.7005
```

This means that if you specify a gain larger than 9.7005, your system will become unstable.  This makes sense with regards to your plot.  We specified gains of 10 and 15, which we would naturally expect to be unstable as a result.

If you wish, you can verify this by using the [Routh-Hurwitz criterion for stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) and building a Routh array and specifically determining the range of stable gains you can use to drive this system and choose the upper limit, which is the critical gain. I'll leave that for you to discover this yourself.